# Uniqueness of the involution on a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

indication please

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Suppose that there exists on $A$ another involution $x\rightarrow x^{\#}$ such that $\|xx^{\#}\|=\|x\|^2$, for all $x\in A$. Prove that $x^{\ast}=x^{\#}$, for all $x \in A$.

Comment: A bit of googling indicates that this was first proved in this 1955 Annals paper by [Bohnenblust and Karlin](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969676?uid=3739464&uid=2129&uid=2134&uid=372970921&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=3&uid=372970911&uid=60&sid=21102467635921), as a consequence of Theorem 9. The geometric idea here is that self-adjoint elements $x$ can be characterized as those such that $u+i\mathbb{R}x$ be tangent to the unit sphere for every $u$ in the unit sphere. So the adjoint is completely determined by the norm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After all, it can be done with standard $C^*$-facts. Here is a detailed sketch.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $A$ is unital. I'll denote $x'$ the second involution.

Let $\phi$ be a linear functional on $A$. Then $\phi$ is positive (preserves positive elements) if and only if $\phi$ is bounded and $\|\phi\|=\phi(1)$ (classic fact).

It follows that the positive linear functionals are the same for both involutions.

To prove that the two involutions are equal, it is clear that it suffices to show that they have the same self-adjoint elements.

So let $h=h^*$. Then for every positive functional $\phi$, we have $\phi(h)\in \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, $\phi(h')=\overline{\phi(h)}$ (why?). So $\phi(h')=\phi(h)$, whence $\phi(i(h'-h))=0$ for every positive functional.

Now for every self-adjoint element $x$, there exists a pure state (extreme point of the state space which is the set of positive functionals of norm $1$) such that $|\phi(x)|=\|x\|$ (classic fact).

Applying this to $i(h'-h)$ yields 
$$
0=|\phi(i(h'-h))|=\|i(h'-h)\|\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad h'=h.
$$
By symmetry, we get $h^*=h$ if and only if $h'=h$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Good reasoning. But when the algebra is only involutive, can we say that the involution is unique??

Comment: @DiegoHavez What do you mean? Only involutive?

Comment: not C*-algebra!!!! only provided with an involution

Comment: @DiegoHavez So you are asking if a Banach *-algebra can have other involutions without the norm axiom of $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: yes exactly julien

Comment: @DiegoHavez For a trivial example, take $A=C([-1,1])$ and consider the involutions $\overline{f(t)}$ and $\overline{f(-t)}$.

Comment: it responds to the question
thank you