# Algebraic isomorphism between two C$^\ast$-algebras implies $\ast$-isomorphic

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite-dimensional C$^\ast$-algebras which are algebraically isomorphic, i.e. there exists a bijective linear map $\Phi:A\rightarrow B$ such that $\Phi(ab)=\Phi(a)\Phi(b)$ for all $a,b \in A$. Is it then true that $\Phi$ is already a $\ast$-isomorphism in the sense that $\Phi$ is isometric and $\Phi(a^\ast)=\Phi(a)^\ast$ for every $a \in A$?

I guess - since injective $\ast$-homomorphism are isometric - it suffices to show that $\Phi$ preserves the involution. For this again it suffices to show that self-adjoint elements are mapped to self-adjoint elements. But how to proceed?

Comment: If you don't require $\Phi$ to be $\mathbb{C}$-linear, then a simple counterexample would be the map from the algebra of $n$-by-$n$ complex matrices to itself given by taking the entrywise complex conjugate. Or I suppose you could even apply a discontinuous field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ to each entry if you aren't asking for continuity. To get a linear counterexample, you could consider conjugation by an invertible, but nonunitary, matrix.

Comment: On the other hand, every $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphism of a C*-algebra that is isometric is automatically $*$-preserving. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444553/uniqueness-of-the-involution-on-a-c-algebra .

Comment: My bad. Of course I want $\Phi$ to be linear. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of your question and the body of your question are actually two distinct questions.
In what follows, I'll appeal to facts about finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras that you can find, for instance, in D. Farenick’s *Algebras of Linear Transformations*, though I don't guarantee that my answer is absolutely optimal in presentation.

The title of your question asks the following: is it true that two finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as unital associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if they are isometrically $\ast$-isomorphic?
The answer to this question is yes.

Recall Wedderburn's theorem for finite-dimensional semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-algebras:

> Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional unital associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ that is semisimple (i.e., is semisimple as a left module over itself).
> There exists a finite list of natural numbers $(n_1,\dotsc,n_k)$, unique up to reordering, such that $A \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ as unital associative algebras.

Now, not only is every finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ semisimple in the above sense, but in this case the isomorphism $A \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^k M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ in Wedderburn's theorem can always be chosen to be a $\ast$-isomorphism, which is therefore bicontinuous (by finite-dimensionality of domain and range) and hence isometric (as a bicontinuous $\ast$-isomorphism between $C^\ast$-algebras).

So, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras that are isomorphic as unital associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$.
By the $C^\ast$-algebraic refinement of Wedderburn's theorem, there exist unique finite non-decreasing lists $(m_1,\dotsc,m_d)$ and $(n_1,\dotsc,n_k)$ of natural numbers, such that $A \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_{m_i}(\mathbb{C})$ and $B \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^k M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$ as unital $C^\ast$-algebras; fix isometric $\ast$-isomorphisms $\phi_A : A \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_{m_i}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\phi_B : B \to \bigoplus_{j=1}^k M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$.
But now, since $A \cong B$ as unital associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$, so too are $\bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_{m_i}(\mathbb{C}) \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^k M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$ as unital associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$, so that by Wedderburn's theorem itself, we must have $(m_1,\dotsc,m_d) = (n_1,\dotsc,n_k)$.
Thus, the isometric $\ast$-isomorphisms $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ have the same range, so that $\phi_B^{-1} \circ \phi_A : A \to B$ is the desired isometric $\ast$-isomorphism.

Now, the body of your question asks the following: given finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and $B$, would an isomorphism $\phi : A \to B$ of unital associative algebras necessarily an isometric $\ast$-isomorphism?
The answer to this is no precisely because there exist unital associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphisms of finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras that are not $\ast$-automorphisms.

For example, let $S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and define a unital associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphism of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ by $$\forall a \in M_2(\mathbb{C}), \quad \phi(a) := SaS^{-1}.$$
Then
$$
 \phi(S)^\ast = (S S S^{-1})^\ast = S^\ast = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
while
$$
 \phi(S^\ast) = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \neq \phi(S)^\ast.
$$

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answer! What I meant to ask was the question in the title and I thought that it would be equivalent to the one in the body. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: You’re welcome. Just to reiterate, once you know that the answer to the question in your title is yes, the question in the body becomes equivalent to asking whether every algebra automorphism of a finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebra is a $\ast$-automorphism, and the answer to *this* question is no.